# Can CreateFile for read access to a physical drive without admin rights?

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I am trying to read some data from the MBR using CreateFile, but I cannot get it to work without admin rights.

The code I am using is like this:

```
hDevice = CreateFile("\\.\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ Or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0)
```

Is it possible to read data from the MBR without admin rights?

Comment: I changed your title, because a non-admin sometimes can open a physical drive depending on what access is requested.

Comment: Read access is generally granted to non-admin users, though I'm not sure in the specific case of physical disks.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot access the physical drive directly without administrative privileges. (Specifically, I think you need SeBackupPrivilege) (Consider what you could do if this was allowed, you could circumvent access control lists saying you were not allowed to read a file)